# How to install Wifi on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

How can I install wifi to Ubuntu 20.04 as the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` is

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38c9]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I also tried:

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh 
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.8.0-53-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.5.2_34066.20200325 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-53-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log for more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.8.0-53-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.5.2_34066.20200325 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-53-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log for more information.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `rtl8821ce-dkms` from universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem once. My mom did the stuff for me, but I remember her saying the example repository on the GUI program for adding repositories was the exact one she needed. I also think it's in the "universe" repository, if I'm understanding the repository indices correctly. So, try adding the example repository on the GUI program for adding repositories, make sure it has the word "universe" (without the quotes) somewhere near the end, and then, while tethered or connected to the internet using Ethernet, or some other way not involving the rtl8821ce card, and try using `sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce` and if that doesn't work, `sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms`.

Dependencies are `bc`, and `dkms` >=2.1.0.0 according to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/rtl8821ce-dkms

I hope my answer helps!

Answer (score -1):

That is so stupid. The whole point of wifi solutions is to be able to use it WITHOUT having access to internet in the first place!? If I had access to the internet to apt-get, why would I be wasting my time trying to install wifi at all? I suppose the laptop users would benefit from this,  but many folks out there use desktops...